# Windows Update / Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, update

Fresh install of Server 2008 R2 with SP1 from disc. Installed all drivers and software needed. Go to Windows Update and change settings to download but NOT install. After 4 hours, it only downloads 3 updates.

Here's the last few lines of the log file:

```
2012-11-15  07:33:11:230    1004    b38 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 55AA099F-30B0-4B1E-A6F0-242CA4CFCFDE is "Priority" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 7591 vs AcceptRate 6738.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:230    1004    b38 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 8885D85B-FCFF-468B-A677-BF5B17320257 is "Priority" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 7591 vs AcceptRate 6738.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:230    1004    b38 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 231BDBA2-E51F-4210-BD28-0BAB1BA17E33 is "Priority" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 7591 vs AcceptRate 6738.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:230    1004    b38 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 0257C940-6D4B-4278-9B5E-A6D88C06E10F is "Priority" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 7591 vs AcceptRate 6738.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:230    1004    b38 DnldMgr Regulation: {7971F918-A847-4430-9279-4A52D1EFE18D} - Update 67F7824D-578E-4126-88A9-2642BEFBC16C is "Priority" regulated and can NOT download. Sequence 7591 vs AcceptRate 6738.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  REPORT EVENT: {FF3D2E27-A036-4428-92D4-A8B20868DC2C}    2012-11-15 07:32:49:015-0500    1   162 101 {133BDE32-024C-48A6-BF83-393E21AF0548}  100 0   AutomaticUpdatesWuApp   Success Content Download    Download succeeded.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  REPORT EVENT: {72231E4C-D335-46B3-85BC-A3A5A93ABA67}    2012-11-15 07:32:49:031-0500    1   188 102 {00000000-0000-0000-
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  REPORT EVENT: {D2DA71EB-4D6A-43D5-BB2C-
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  REPORT EVENT: {ECBF0A1A-C3B5-4628-A5BB-1887A2B99FC4}    2012-11-15 07:33:00:310-0500    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0       Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 65 updates.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1536    914 COMAPI  >>--  RESUMED  -- COMAPI: Search [ClientId = <NULL>]
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  REPORT EVENT: {6C051E8A-B775-493E-8E92-3BF95C5400A0}    2012-11-15 07:33:11:168-0500    1   147 101 {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}  0   0       Success Software Synchronization    Windows Update Client successfully detected 65 updates.
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:246    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
2012-11-15  07:33:11:292    1536    914 COMAPI    - Updates found = 65
2012-11-15  07:33:11:292    1536    914 COMAPI  ---------
2012-11-15  07:33:11:292    1536    914 COMAPI  --  END  --  COMAPI: Search [ClientId = <NULL>]
2012-11-15  07:33:11:292    1536    914 COMAPI  -------------
2012-11-15  07:33:16:175    1004    b38 Report  CWERReporter finishing event handling. (00000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to let those 3 updates install first.
They update WindowsUpdate itself.
Afterwards it will function more or less as expected.

Please note that at any time you may see that not all updates are offered because of the simple fact that some updates require that another update is installed first.
Such updates are only offered/downloaded **after** the installation of the requirede update(s).